# How to pad a pointer array

Tags: c++

I've applied a Guassian blur to an image now need to take care of the edge pixels. I've decided to pad the initial pixel array to take care of this issue.

How could I pad a pointer array?

```
int *myArray = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Which is basically a 2D array of:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

How could I convert this to the following pointer array (1 padding):

```
0 1 2 3 0
1 1 2 3 3
4 4 5 6 6
7 7 8 9 9
0 7 8 9 0
```

2 padding:

```
0 0 1 2 3 0 0
0 0 1 2 3 0 0
1 1 1 2 3 3 3
4 4 4 5 6 6 6
7 7 7 8 9 9 9
0 0 7 8 9 0 0
0 0 7 8 9 0 0
```

And so fourth.

Comment: Which library do you use?

Comment: Whoops! There we go. I create the kernel function myself. I'm using Free image plus library to get the image pixels

Comment: I prefer not to invent data around the image buffers when running filters, but instead treat them as background values and not include them in the calculations at all. If you are going to extend the data like that, I do suggest you fill the corners with something though.

Comment: Is a C-array a must? Why aren'y you using a Vector?

Comment: Since your padded table is bigger than your original table, you'll certainly need to create a brand new bigger table, initialize the four corners to 0 (at least), copy the central elements, and fill the sides accordingly. Btw, I'd suggest you use `std::vector` rather than a raw pointer to store that table (or any class offered by a more specialized third party library if you use one), it'll easier to avoid memory leaks and/or silly mistakes.

Comment: Well, write a function that takes an array and the padding level and returns the padded array.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your last line with two-padding.

Comment: Or whatever is doing the conversion, have it use a getter fn with x&y values; then you don't need to re-create the array and copy, but just adjust the indexes or return 0